# Amazon S3 Bucket cache clear

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

I have hosted a static site in an Amazon S3 bucket with Route 53 and CloudFront configuration.

While updating a file in the S3 bucket I am unable to view the updated file in the browser - it still loads from the cache. (I tried clearing the cache in the browser.)

Any suggestion how to clear the S3 bucket cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the file is **cached in Amazon CloudFront**.

You can [Invalidate Files in Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) to have the next request pull the file from S3 again.

You can also set the **cache duration**, which is how long CloudFront will continue to serve content before checking whether the source file has changed.